# Unity Build Doast work the same as The Editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing some problems with the unity build, its seems like the build of my game and the unity editor do not work the same.
the build missing 50% of the scripts I made and some scripts that do exists or work there have some of their functionality missing for example:
A certain script would spawn 4 game objects when passing "space" but its spawn only one.
Also, objects that cast shadows in the editor don't do so in the build.
Ui do not function as we script it to. 
In other works almost nothing works.

our unity vision is 2019.3.0f5.
We did make sure our scene itself is Exaptionless no bugs with or code.
We tried it on 5 different computers for the same results and its already 2 weeks of struggles trying to run it on different build settings.

Comment: Hi,  2019.3.0f5 was a beta version, however, it sounds odd that its not working.  What is the build target? Have you used the new input system? Ive certainly built things and have to say nothings gone missing..

Comment: Note that the [tag:unityscript] tag is for a JavaScript-like language that was deprecated in 2018.  If you're using C#, you aren't using UnityScript.

Comment: F# versions are never beta versions @BugFinder

Comment: Clearly you missed the fact that it was still in beta until yesterday and yesterday’s release was f6. They use f’s as release candidates for the beta. And most of those were bad  @smileynator

Comment: If that is the case they are slipping on their own naming conventions. Last time i heard it was f# for normal releases. b# for beta releases, and p# for quick patches that were severe enough to not wait for an f# release. Either way, using a LTS version is highly recommended. Don't use any new feature for at least 6 months until after stable release of that feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you are trying to do this might have a lot of causes.
Debug log your event system to see what is actually being done with UI. It might be something overlaying strangely due to the different screen size etc. UI scaling.

For the shadows, that is a build setting. Editor and Build have a default Quality setting. Per platform etc. You can check the "Quality Settings" for your project to see what the defaults are and change them.

As for other scripts, again logs. Make sure that in Start/Awake there is a Debug.Log. And check the log file that the build creates when you play the game. If your logs do not come back in that log file, you know something is up. @schneebuzz's suggestion on editor only scripts might be one of the causes there among many.

Comment: It seems that it does add all the scripts to the build, but I still can't tell why they do not take effect or just happen to do half of what they created for. the log doesn't give me any exceptions about them.

Comment: I used debug log to make sure everything that I spawn with "space" is still in the list and yes it is in the build but yet it still spawns just one

Comment: Well i suggest learning to hook the debug build to visual studio and stepping through the code then. Something has to go wrong somewhere and it can help you figure out what by breakpoints.